# React/Flux - How to scale stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Reading the Facebook/Flux website they give an example where by they have stores for 'Messages', 'Threads' and 'Unread Threads'. My understanding is that 'Threads' and 'Unread Threads' are the within the same domain. The point being made in their example is that you might want to track the state of the same data but from different contexts?

In my example I'm working with a list of 'leads' and depending on the component I am using (or mode of the component) and I need to view different subsets of the data. The REST call accepts a 'filter' option which I can easily supply through react props but this doesn't feel like a scalable approach:

```
<LeadsList filterBy="status:active" />
```

The dashboard I created only concerns itself with 'active' leads and uses the LeadsList component this way. LeadsList could however be used in other places without filtering etc. That was my goal here.

My overall question is: should I create a separate store for 'active leads' or filter through one central store?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one right way to do it. You can process filters on the server or the client. You can use one store or many. For a large data set it might be best to process on the server. For a smaller data set processing on the client should be fine. How many stores you use depends on how you want to conceptually manage the data. The goal beyond functionality is clarity and maintainability.

For instance with reflux I can have one store for each logical page and use mixins to combine stores for each unique data set into the page store. That provides a separation of concerns for me while only needing one store be handled by the control component for that page.

Here is an example from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxSuperAgent.

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from '../actions/sa.Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
 init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
 data1: {},
 listenables: Actions,
 mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
 onGotData1: _GotData,
 onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
 getData1() { return this.data1; },
 getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
 getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

import BasicStore from '../stores/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

const getState = () => {
 return {
  Data1: BasicStore.getData1(),
  Data2: BasicStore.getData2(),
  Data3: BasicStore.getData3()
 };
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let data1 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data1, null, 2);
  let data2 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data2, null, 2);
  let data3 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data3, null, 2);
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux with SuperAgent<br/><br/>
    Data1: {data1}<br/><br/>
    Data2: {data2}<br/><br/>
    Data3: {data3}<br/><br/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount() { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange.bind(this)); }
 componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange(id) {
  switch (id) {
   case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
   case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
   case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
   default: this.setState(getState());
  }
 }
}
```